# Python - strategy to construct triplet tuples from pair tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't think the title does a great job acting as a high level explanation of the problem, but I do think this is an interesting problem to try to solve:

Given a python list of tuples of length 2:

```
pairs = [('G', 'H'), ('C', 'D'), ('B', 'D'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C')]
```

I would like to create a new list containing tuples of length 3, on the condition that the tuple ('X', 'Y', 'Z') is created only if the pairs ('X', 'Y'), ('Y', 'Z'), and ('X', 'Z') all appear as tuples in the pairs list. In the case of my pairs list, only the triplet ('B', 'C', 'D') would be created (preferably alphabetically).

I haven't used python in several months, so am a bit rusty and would prefer to solve this using mostly base python packages, but open to any suggestions. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: is this a bad post?

Comment: You haven't posted code showing what you've tried.  So technically it's not a great post.  Anyhow...  you could create a set that contains all of the elements of all the tuples (this makes sure that each element is only there once).  Then create a list of all the elements in the set and sort it.  Now you have an ordered list of unique elements.  You can then traverse your ordered list looking for a sequence of three incremental elements in a row, and if so, write them to your output.  Keep traversing the list for more sequences of three.

Comment: Write down on paper how you think this can be solved  - include that process in your post and maybe an attempt at writing that process as pseudocode.

Comment: okay got it will do

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `itertools` to check if all the pairs exist.

```
from itertools import combinations

doubles = [('G', 'H'), ('C', 'D'), ('B', 'D'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C')]
keys = set([x for double in doubles for x in double])
options = combinations(keys, 3)

triples = list()
for option in options:
    x, y, z = sorted(option)
    first, second, third = (x, y), (x, z), (y, z)
    if first in doubles and second in doubles and third in doubles:
        triples.append(option)
```

This assumes that all the tuples in your list are already sorted though.

Answer (score 0):

```
vals = set([i for (i, j) in pairs] + [j for (i, j) in pairs])

triples = [(i, j, k) for i in vals 
                         for j in vals 
                             for k in vals 
           if (((i, j) in pairs) and 
               ((j, k) in pairs) and  
               ((i, k) in pairs))]
```

Now, this only works if the order of the tuples matter. If not, you'd want to include the reverse-order tuples in `pairs` as well